# How do you INSERT into influxDB using the SQL-like interface?

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to `INSERT` data into series / measurements using the SQL-like interface on InfluxDB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can simply [`INSERT` a Line Protocol string](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/tools/shell/#write-data-to-influxdb-with-insert).

An example from [Getting Started](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/introduction/getting_started/):

```
INSERT cpu,host=serverA,region=us_west value=0.64
```

A point with the measurement name of `cpu` and tags `host` and `region` has now been written to the database, with the measured `value` of `0.64`.

Comment: Since "value" a keyword, I think it would be clearer if it were uppercased in this example (to show newbies that it's not just another tag name)

Comment: Can i insert multiple values like value=0.64, value1=100??

Comment: @BenSlade `value` is not a keyword. It's the name of your "field". (`cpu` is the "measurement".) You can name your fields whatever you like, e.g. `temp`. @Hacker yes you can have many, e.g. `load_avg=0.64,temp=90`.