# Why is this simple influx select query returning an empty result?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

Following from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459151/1663462

```
> use abcxyz;
Using database abcxyz
> INSERT cpu,host=serverA,region=us_west value=0.64
> SELECT * from abcxyz;
> SELECT cpu from abcxyz;
```

Why are the `SELECT` queries returning no results?

---

I've found a query that works:

```
select * from cpu;
name: cpu
time                host    region  value
----                ----    ------  -----
1555173896021474852 serverA us_west 0.64
1555173957479404100 serverA us_west 0.64
1555173967231619401 serverA us_west 0.64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT` works against measurements, which exist within a database. You can think of a measurement as a table in standard RDBMS software.

So `SELECT fields_or_tags FROM measurement` is the correct syntax

Comment: Should it not have shown an error then, when selecting from a measurement that doesn't exit?